# simplexml and using relative path

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to get to a part in an xml response, without following the whole path. Now I know that xpath has search abilities, but somehow I dont understand it... :(

The XML i am parsing is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapEnvelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <envHeader xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsaAction>http://www.rechtspraak.nl/namespaces/cir01/searchUndertakingResponse</wsaAction>
        <wsaMessageID>urn:uuid:11f7d4cd-2280-4298-85eb-dadf5bd743f1</wsaMessageID>
        <wsaRelatesTo>urn:uuid:59630fbd-b990-4020-9c1c-822c58186d96</wsaRelatesTo>
        <wsaTo>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsaTo>
        <wsseSecurity>
            <wsuTimestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-df25f141-fed2-47ed-967e-93cd04d1c8f2">
                <wsuCreated>2011-04-02T06:52:52Z</wsuCreated>
                <wsuExpires>2011-04-02T06:57:52Z</wsuExpires>
            </wsuTimestamp>
        </wsseSecurity>
    </envHeader>
    <soapBody>
        <searchUndertakingResponse xmlns="http://www.rechtspraak.nl/namespaces/cir01"><searchUndertakingResult>
                <publicatieLijst xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" extractiedatum="2011-04-02T08:52:51" xmlns="http://www.rechtspraak.nl/namespaces/inspubber01">
                    <publicatieKenmerk>sgr.10.787.F.1300.1.10</publicatieKenmerk>
                    <publicatieKenmerk>utr.10.585.F.1300.1.10</publicatieKenmerk>
                </publicatieLijst>
            </searchUndertakingResult>
        </searchUndertakingResponse>
    </soapBody>
</soapEnvelope>
```

And I am looking for these values: `<publicatieKenmerk>sgr.10.787.F.1300.1.10</publicatieKenmerk>   <publicatieKenmerk>utr.10.585.F.1300.1.10</publicatieKenmerk>`

Now this works:

```
$lijst = $results->soapBody->searchUndertakingResponse->searchUndertakingResult->publicatieLijst->publicatieKenmerk;
    foreach ($lijst AS $kenmerk) {
        echo $kenmerk."<BR>";
    }
```

But I dont want to use this, as I need to be flexible for other results. and cannot rely on 
searchUndertakingResponse->searchUndertakingResult

So I was hoping to use xpath to get there, but this doesnt work:

```
 $lijst = $results->xpath('//publicatieKenmerk');
    foreach($lijst as $kenmerk) {
        echo $kenmerk."<br />";
    }
```

But I thought relative would work as well... any ideas?

Comment: I think this is job for preg_match and regular expression or xml parser, but I'm not good on this. Hope some other guys will post piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that your `<publicatieLijst>` node has a default namespace set: `xmlns="http://www.rechtspraak.nl/namespaces/inspubber01"` which means that `<publicatieKenmerk>` exists that namespace. That's why `//publicatieKenmerk` won't find it, you have to search in the right namespace.

For that, you can register the namespace with your own prefix and use that prefix in the following XPath query, like this:

```
$soapEnvelope = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$soapEnvelope->registerXPathNamespace(
    'inspubber01',
    'http://www.rechtspraak.nl/namespaces/inspubber01'
);

foreach ($soapEnvelope->xpath('//inspubber01:publicatieKenmerk') as $publicatieKenmerk)
{
    echo $publicatieKenmerk, "\n";
}
```

Comment: that is actually even neater coded... thanks for that...code adjusted accordingly....

Answer (score 1):

can you try to change on they way it loops?

```
    while(list( , $node) = each($lijst)) {
    echo 'kenmerk: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

Comment: I think it's because of the different namespace. Try selecting the node with `http://www.rechtspraak.nl/namespaces/inspubber01` namespace

Comment: simplest way is to remove the namespace `<?php
$string = str_replace('xmlns=', 'ns=', $string); //$string is a string that contains xml...
?>` from http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Modifying XML content with string functions is rarely (if ever) a good idea. You risk completely screwing up your script with that kind of hack. XML is actually a pretty simple format, it's a more efficient use of your time familiarizing with it rather than trying to bypass it completely.